# JasperReports: How to construct the title header depending on parameters

Tags: jasper-reports

How to construct the title header depending on parameters?

Example, I have one reports by date, weekly, month and year. I have a parameter but I don't know how to display it in header.

What I want is:

```
If I put parameter $P{date1} and $P{date2} then it will show 'Date range from $P{date1} and $P{date2}' for header 1

else if parameter $P{w}$P{month}$P{year} then 'For weekly $P{w}$P{month}$P{year}' for header 2

else if parameter $P{month}$P{year} then 'For monthly $P{month}$P{year}' for header 3

else if parameter $P{q}$P{year} then 'For quarter $P{q}$P{year}' for header 4

else if parameter $P{year} then 'For yearly $P{year}' for header 5
```

UPDATE:-
i have new problem when i run the report,my output not display correctly.
This is my code:-

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Company Profile by Date Registered" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="NoDataSection" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" isFloatColumnFooter="true">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <parameter name="daterangefrom" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="daterangeto" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="monthy" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="yrs" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="quarter" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="weeks" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select a.entered,
a.modified,
a.org_id,
a.name,
a.organization_type,
c.description as companygroup,lead,
a.industry_temp_code,
b.description,
a.equity_structure,a.operation_date from organization a
left join lookup_industry_group b on a.industry_temp_code = b.code
left join lookup_company_group c on c.code = a.company_group
left join ticket d on d.org_id = a.org_id
where
((d.entered BETWEEN $P{daterangefrom} AND $P{daterangeto}) or ($P{daterangefrom} =' ' AND $P{daterangeto} =' '))
AND
((datename(month,d.entered) = $P{monthy}) or ($P{monthy} = ' '))
AND
((datename(year,d.entered) = $P{yrs}) or ($P{yrs} = ' '))
AND
((datepart(qq, d.entered) = $P{quarter}) or ($P{quarter} = ' '))
AND
((DATEPART(day, d.entered - 1) / 7 + 1 = $P{weeks}) or  ($P{weeks} = ' '))]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="entered" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
    <field name="modified" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
    <field name="org_id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="organization_type" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="companygroup" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="lead" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="industry_temp_code" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="description" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="equity_structure" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="operation_date" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="18" y="14" width="537" height="41" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[(($P{daterangefrom} != null) && ($P{daterangeto} != null)) ?  "Date range from " + $P{daterangefrom} + " and " + $P{daterangeto}
: (($P{weeks} != null) && ($P{monthy} != null) && ($P{yrs} != null)) ? "For weekly " +$P{weeks} + $P{monthy} + $P{yrs}
: (($P{monthy} != null) && ($P{yrs} != null)) ? "For monthly " + $P{monthy} + $P{yrs}
: (($P{quarter} != null) &&  ($P{yrs} != null)) ? "For quarter " + $P{quarter} + $P{yrs}
: (($P{yrs} != null)) ? "For yearly " + $P{yrs} : null]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the *`textField`* element to the `Title` band and set the *`textFieldExpression`* property.

You should use the conditional operator ***`? :`*** in expression.

The sample (the snippet of jrxml file):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport ...>
    <parameter name="date1" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[null]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="date2" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[null]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="w" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[null]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="q" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[null]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="month" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[null]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="year" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[null]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="18" y="14" width="537" height="41"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{date1} != null && $P{date2} != null ?  "Date range from " + $P{date1} + " and " + $P{date2}
: $P{w} != null && $P{month} != null && $P{year} ? "For weekly " + $P{w} + $P{month} + $P{year}
: $P{month} != null && $P{year} != null ? "For monthly " + $P{month} + $P{year}
: $P{q} != null &&  $P{year} != null ? "For quarter " + $P{q} + $P{year}
: $P{year} != null ? "For yearly " + $P{year} : null]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: i have try your code but the error show.can you check it.This is my code:-$P{daterangefrom} != null &&$P{daterangeto} != null ?  "Date range from " +$P{daterangefrom} + " and " + $P{daterangeto}
:$P{weeks} != null && $P{monthy} != null && $P{yrs} ? "For weekly " + $P{weeks} + $P{monthy} + $P{yrs}
:$P{monthy} != null && $P{yrs} != null ? "For monthly " +$P{monthy} + $P{yrs}
:$P{quarter} != null &&  $P{yrs} != null ? "For quarter " +$P{quarter} + $P{yrs}
:$P{yrs} != null ? "For yearly " + $P{yrs} : null

Comment: Errors compiling C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\daterange2.jasper!
Compilation exceptions: com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.ErrorsCollector@1828e3d  net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed: calculator_daterange_1333704045656_558975: 299: expecting ':', found '<newline>' @ line 299, column 289. 1 error

Comment: yes. i have check your textFieldExpression but the problem still same.

Comment: You can try to set Java language for the report, not the Groovy

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9771/discussion-between-alex-k-and-amin)

Comment: i have problem with my code when i change to java. the problem is my output display the text when no data. Not for the null data.i have update my code at above. Can you check what wrong with my code?.i hope you can reply immediately.Thank you.